# Android - smoothScrollBy float number

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I'm building a timeline by using a `recyclerview` each row represents x amount of seconds and y the height of each row.

I would like to automatically scroll as time goes by seconds, however, since each row represents more than 1 second, I need to scroll by fraction within each row to represent a second. Does anyone have an idea how could I achieve this? I've look and I'm not able to find a method that takes a Float number, just Int.

Can't do this because `smoothScrollBy` doesn't take a Float.

```
val time = rowHeight.toFloat() / secondsPerRow.toFloat()
timelineRecyclerView.smoothScrollBy(0, time)
```

Comment: smoothScrollBy scrolls by pixels, why are you using floats?

Comment: `smoothScrollBy` is scrolling by the specified number of pixels.  Why not just use `time.toInt()`?

Comment: @CSmith I want each row to be around 120 seconds and the height of each row about 5; therefore ```time```  equals to 0 and recyclerview doesn't scroll. I will try to make it work having it by int.

Comment: I surely don't understand what you're trying to do .. a row height of 5 pixels is very small.  Anyhow it seems to be just math ... and whether you use Int's or Floats you'll need to round to the nearest whole pixel for scrolling operations.

Comment: @CSmith, I'm tying to build a timeline similar to Nest Camera, however, I wanted to have each row of the recyclerview to be 5 px height and each row would be 120 seconds, therefore,  if I want to scroll automatically by seconds, I would need to scroll very finite within each row. I will try to make it work with Int.